# Mesclar 2 tabelas diferentes e exibir conteúdo ordenando por número de visualizações (maior para menor) das duas juntas no MySQL

Tags: mysql

Considerando que eu tenha 2 tabelas no BD, "noticias" e "novidades", cada qual com campos próprios:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível fazer um `SELECT` nas duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo de modo que me retorne os 4 maiores valores dos campos "impressoes" (tabela NOTICIAS)  e "cliques" (tabela NOVIDADES), os dois combinados?

O resultado esperado seria este (ordenando do maior para o menor):

1. Errado (15 visualizações)
2. Olá (9 visualizações)
3. Médio (6 visualizações)
4. Bom (5 visualizações)

Comment: As tabelas não tem nenhuma relação de chave estrangeira??

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Desculpe, mas não entendi a sua pergunta.

Comment: o id de novidades é o mesmo id de noticias?

Comment: Se existe algum vinculo entre as tabelas, se uma possui um campo chave da outra.

Comment: @MarllonNasser As tabelas tem IDs próprios e uma não tem nenhuma relação com a outra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from 
(select titulo, impressoes as visualizacoes
from 
noticias 
union ALL
select titulo, cliques as visualizacoes
from cliques) result order by result.visualizacoes desc
limit 0,4
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3e9f/16)

Comment: Ele só quer as 4 maiores, creio q uma simples adição ao seu código com `limit 1,4` resolva.

Comment: `limit 0,4`. Editei :)

Comment: É verdade, 0,4 kkk

Comment: @MarllonNasser Funcionou perfeitamente! Mt obrigado!